# SSRS Expression to show String array

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have following custom code which finds given string in the input string and returns array of strings accordingly.

```
Public Function ConvertCode(ParamValues As String, findString As String) As String()
Dim SrcArray() As String
Dim FndArray() As String
Dim DstArray() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
SrcArray = Split(ParamValues, ",")
FndArray = Split(FindString,",")
For k = LBound(FndArray) To UBound(FndArray)
For i = LBound(SrcArray) To UBound(SrcArray)
    If (InStr(SrcArray(i), FndArray(k)) > 0) Then
        DstArray(j) = SrcArray(i)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
Next k
ConvertCode  =  DstArray
End Function
```

I am using SSRS expression to get the value returned from this code.

```
=Join(Code.ConvertCode(Join(Parameters!ProcessingStatus.Value,","),"reject,fail,Reject,Fail"),",")
```

If there are no matching eleents in the ProcessingStatus it returns correctly and shows nothing but if there is matching strng then it is returning as #Error. Please help me.

Comment: How do you intend to use the array of strings output? btw you need to add j = 0 as this variable is not initialised. However, this is not the answer to your problem. An example input / output expected might help!

Comment: You also need to set a dimension size of DstArray. Both the other arrays are filled using the Split